# Assigned_by_id bitrix

Tags: битрикс, crm, интеграция

При создании связи форма-crm столкнулся с проблемой. Создаю лид через admin'a с ID=1. Нужно ответственным поставить пользователя с ID=10. Но при любом ID, кроме своего не создается лид.

код:

```
$arParams = array(
'LOGIN' => $login,
'PASSWORD' => $password,
'TITLE' => 'Contacts',
'NAME' => $_POST[PROPERTY][NAME][0],
'EMAIL_WORK' => $_POST[PROPERTY][2088][0],
'COMMENTS' => $_POST[PROPERTY][PREVIEW_TEXT][0],
'ASSIGNED_BY_ID' => 10
);
if ($_POST[iblock_submit] != '') {
$obHttp = new \Bitrix\Main\Web\HttpClient;
$result = $obHttp->Post($crmUrl.'crm/configs/import/lead.php', $arParams);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Хоть вопрос наверно уже неактуален, добавлю свой комментарий для других пользователей. Открыл шаблон проекта, где всё работает, и там в $arParams, кроме ASSIGNED_BY_ID, указан также параметр CREATED_BY_ID. В нём задан этот же ID. Попробуйте, может поможет